# CSS layout Tic Tac Toe

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe game. Now while designing the board I made 3 squares in 3 rows and put a display of inline-block on the squares. For convenience I put the Xs in the squares while designing it and it came perfectly. But now when I put a single X i.e when player clicks on a particular square the square gets pushed down.[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/helsey/pen/oEGrjy?editors=1100).

```css
.sq {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: -3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="sq 1 bottom right">X</div>
  <div class="sq 2 bottom right"></div>
  <div class="sq 3 bottom "></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="sq 4 bottom right"></div>
  <div class="sq 5 bottom right"></div>
  <div class="sq 6 bottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="sq 7 right"></div>
  <div class="sq 8 right"></div>
  <div class="sq 9"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.sq`  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvXNqY?editors=1100

```
vertical-align: top;
```

the default of vertical align is baseline, so when you have a X in one box and not the other the baseline is different for the boxes, if you align them to the top, it will display properly

```
.sq{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; // new
  height:90px;
  width:120px;
  margin-right:-3px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:40px;
  padding-top:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  transition:background 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks..didn't knew about the vertical align property

Answer (score 0):

Change your style to this:

```
.sq {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transition: background 0.3s;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Oops, didn't see the other answer! So fast